# Print Years in reverse order starting from this year to last 10 years in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to print years in reverse order starting from this year (2016) e.g.:

```
2016
2015
2014
..
2006
```

for this I use 'for' loop:

```
$year1 = date("Y");
$endyear = date("Y")-10;
for ($year = $year1; $year < $endyear; $year--) {
    echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}
```

But it doesn't show any output. even if I use this same code for increment the years for 10 years, like

```
$year1 = date("Y");
$endyear = date("Y")+10;
for ($year = $year1; $year < $endyear; $year++) {
    echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}
```

its output is;

```
The year is: 2016
The year is: 2017
The year is: 2018
The year is: 2019
The year is: 2020
The year is: 2021
The year is: 2022
The year is: 2023
The year is: 2024
The year is: 2025
```

I there something I am doing wrong in my code. Please help me to achieve this in reverse order.

Comment: `range(2025, 2016)`

Comment: The three answers are the correct answers, I don't know why them receives downvotes, my upvote to all of them. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition in the `for` loop is wrong. According to your question this is the correct code:

```
<?php

$year1 = date("Y");
$endyear = date("Y")-10;
for ($year = $year1; $year >= $endyear; $year--) {
    echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you needed to do is to flip the `<`

```
$year1 = date("Y");
$endyear = date("Y")-10;
for ($year = $year1; $year > $endyear; $year--) {
    echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not `$year < $endyear`
but: $year > $endyear

so:

```
$year1 = date("Y");
$endyear = date("Y")-10;
for ($year = $year1; $year > $endyear; $year--) {
    echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:-

```
$years = range(date("Y")+9,date("Y")); // range(2025,2016)
foreach($years as $year){
  echo "The year is: $year <br>";
}
```